Can ERC-4671 NTTs only be issued by third-party authorities?
I'm not trying to make anything in particular, but I'm new to Ethereum and just curious about the following:
I've been reading about Non-tradable tokens (NTTs) and the ERC-4671 standard developed for them. In the docs, it only mentions authorities (ie. schools, governments, business etc) being able to mint these tokens. For example in the 'Specifications' section, it states "A NTT contract is seen as representing one type of certificate delivered by one authority." Nowhere else in the documentation does it mention users being able to mint NTTs themselves.
Does that imply that it is impossible for users to mint their own NTTs using this interface? Can there be a work around? (I can't really read solidity, yet. So can't tell from the code).
Thanks
